# Video input works but same input from camera gives false positives

Tags: python, tensorflow, yolov4

I am using yolov4 to automatically reject items on a conveyor belt which are clumped together. Items which are nicely spaced apart are allowed to pass onto the next operation.

I just trained a new model which works great when I test it with video but produces false positives when testing with input from the camera. This is the very same camera I used to collect the images for training the model. And when I run the classifier from either camera or video input it looks exactly the same to me. The video input that I used for testing is not the same as the video input that was used for training the model. So there must be something about the camera input which is different from the video input and makes a difference to the classifier. But I don't know what that is.

I did query the classifier for differences between video input and camera input and got the following. I could try setting all of these the same but then I am sure that this will cause the two inputs to look different whereas they look the same when using the current settings. So I don't know why the classifier works so much better when taking input from the video.
Has anyone seen this issue before?

The camera is reporting the following settings.

```
CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS is -23.0  :
CAP_PROP_CONTRAST is 30.0  :
CAP_PROP_HUE is 0.0  :
CAP_PROP_SATURATION is 60.0  :
CAP_PROP_SHARPNESS is 0.0  :
CAP_PROP_GAMMA is 100.0  :
CAP_PROP_GAIN is 228.0  :
CAP_PROP_HEIGHT is 480.0  :
CAP_PROP_WIDTH is 640.0  :
CAP_PROP_FPS : '0.0'
CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE : '-6.0'
```

The video is reporting the following settings.

```
CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS is 0.0  :
CAP_PROP_CONTRAST is 0.0  :
CAP_PROP_HUE is 0.0  :
CAP_PROP_SATURATION is 0.0  :
CAP_PROP_SHARPNESS is 0.0  :
CAP_PROP_GAMMA is 0.0  :
CAP_PROP_GAIN is 0.0  :
CAP_PROP_HEIGHT is 480.0  :
CAP_PROP_WIDTH is 640.0  :
CAP_PROP_FPS : '30.0'
CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE : '0.0'
```

Comment: You've either over trained the network or you have a weighting issue. The training data is probably biased unless you manually selected a 50/50 split (positive/negative). And even that can cause some issues. My advice would be to retrain the network with a class weight bias. This is typically how fraud detection is accomplished.

Comment: It seems rather pointless to compare most properties. Only width and height are consistently filled in.

Comment: Thanks @StenHealey, Yes, likely over-trained and definitely biased toward positive. Still I don't understand why video input taken from the camera would work where as input directly from the camera gives false positives. In any case I will train less and change the bias and then report back here.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation @MSalters. I didn't think the actual settings were the issue here. I did suspect that height and width could be a factor but these are same for video and direct camera input.

Comment: Is the distinction _really_ the path? When I first read this question, my first thought is that your training and test data have something in common your live feed doesn't -- that could be lighting levels, it could be the amount of noise in the video stream; part of the effect of overtraining on a single dataset is that your model learns details of that dataset that don't necessarily map to the real world thing you're trying to identify. (For that matter, is your camera used for testing identical hardware at an identical angle? etc).

Comment: Twenty-*mumble* years ago, my AI professor pulled out an example of a model that was _supposedly_ being trained to distinguish between Soviet and American tanks actually learning to distinguish between tanks photographed in optimal and suboptimal conditions (because the Soviet data was collected without consent of its owners, whereas the US data was collected on sunny days with perfect conditions for overhead photography).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, The video I used to test is different than the video which was used to capture images for training. But in both cases, the video was taken under the exact same conditions with the exact same camera at the exact same angle and looking at the same kind of items. Yes, the model is likely overtrained and biased so I will address these but I am confused why video feed is working well where as direct camera input is not. While the video feed is not the training data it is older. I will make a new video from the camera and see if the results are the same as direct camera input.

Comment: I took a new video with the same camera that I was using for detection and then used that video for input. This gave me the same false positives. So I must have changed the camera settings since training. I can't believe I forgot. So yes, the model is over-trained and biased but I may be able to compensate by changing camera settings. That was unexpected. I will of course fix the model too. I will do these one at a time and report back. Thank you all for putting me on the correct path.